# Symfony 3.4 - Passing variables in my modals?

Tags: symfony, modal-dialog

I would like to know if it is possible to pass variables in a modal using Symfony?

Before integrating a modal, my line looked like

```
<a href="{{ path('paquets_delete', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type':unType['typeUtilisateur'] }) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</a>
```

It is used to delete a line from my database.

I wanted to add a modal sign confirmation request.
Then I added a modal and now I have this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</a>
```

The modal :

```
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#HereIWantMyVariablesForMyControllerPathRendering" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Is there a parameter to put in my link calling the modal, to place the variables?

EDIT:

After using macros, by Fabian, here is my code:

**Views/macro/macro.html.twig:**

```
{%- macro create_delete_modal(body, deleteLink) -%}
    {% filter spaceless %}
        <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Supprimer?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>{{ body }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="{{ deleteLink }}" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfilter %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

**Controller delete fonction:**

```
/**
 * Suppression d'un package | Suppression d'un type d'utilisateur attribué à un package
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/{type}/delete", name="paquets_delete")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id, $type)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $unPaquet = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Paquet')->find($id); //Récupération du package

    $nbTypes = count($unPaquet->getTypeUser()); //Récupération du nombre de TypeUser auquel est attribué le package


    if($nbTypes == 1)
    {
        $em->remove($unPaquet); // Si un seul destinataire, on supprimme le package.
    }

    else if($nbTypes > 1)
    {
        $am = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $leType = $am->getRepository('PagesBundle:TypeUser')->findByTypeUtilisateur($type);
        $unPaquet->deleteTypeFromTypesUser($leType[0]); // Si plusieurs destinataires, on supprimme juste le type d'utilisateur passé en paramètre
    }

    $em->flush(); // Validation



    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->updateNbDDLAll("dec"); // A la suppression d'un package, on décrémente le nombre de télécharme

    $this->addFlash( // Message d'information à l'admin
        'info_delete',
        'Package supprimée !'
    );

    return $this->redirectToRoute('paquets_index'); // Actualisation de la page
}
```

**index.html.twig :**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% import 'macro/macro.html.twig' as macro %}


{% block body %}
<br/>
<a href="{{ path('paquets_new') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Ajouter un package</a>
<br/> <br/>
{% for unType in typesUser %}
{% set i=loop.index0 %}
<h1 class="text-primary text-center">{{unType['typeUtilisateur']}} <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill w3-small">{{ tabInfos[i]|length }}</span></h1>
<br />

<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Titre</th>
            <th>Package</th>
            <th>Notice</th>
            <th>Commentaire</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for uneInfo in tabInfos[i] %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('paquets_show', { 'id': uneInfo.id }) }}">{{ uneInfo.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ uneInfo.titre }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('paquet_fileDDL', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type': 'package'}) }}"</a>{{ uneInfo.urlPaquet }} </td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('paquet_fileDDL', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type': 'notice'}) }}"</a>{{ uneInfo.urlNotice }} </td>
            <td>{{ uneInfo.commentaire }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('paquets_edit', { 'id': uneInfo.id }) }}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Modifier</a>
                {#<a href="{{ path('paquets_delete', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type':unType['typeUtilisateur'] }) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</a> #}
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</button>
                {{ macro.create_delete_modal('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce package ? ', path('paquets_delete', {'id':uneInfo.id, 'type': unType['typeUtilisateur']})) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/><br/>


{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**The most important part of the html.twig:**

```
{% for uneInfo in tabInfos[i] %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('paquets_show', { 'id': uneInfo.id }) }}">{{ uneInfo.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ uneInfo.titre }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('paquet_fileDDL', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type': 'package'}) }}"</a>{{ uneInfo.urlPaquet }} </td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('paquet_fileDDL', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type': 'notice'}) }}"</a>{{ uneInfo.urlNotice }} </td>
            <td>{{ uneInfo.commentaire }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('paquets_edit', { 'id': uneInfo.id }) }}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Modifier</a>
  
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</button>
                {{ macro.create_delete_modal('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce package ? ', path('paquets_delete', {'id':uneInfo.id, 'type': unType['typeUtilisateur']})) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

[image]

The problem: it removes the first packages, not the ones I want to delete

Comment: Look at my edit again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomment you to use a [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) for your modal. This one you can reuse everytime you want. This would look something like this:

```
{%- macro create_delete_modal(body, deleteLink) -%}
    {% filter spaceless %}
        <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Supprimer?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>{{ body }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="{{ deleteLink }}" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfilter %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

And to use it:

```
{% import 'macro/macro.html.twig' as macro %}

{{ macro.create_delete_modal('Are you sure you want to delete this?',  path('paquets_delete', { 'id': uneInfo.id, 'type':unType['typeUtilisateur'] }) }}

<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</button>
```

---

**Edit**

The id of the modal (`id="#deleteModal"`) is not unique any more, as you loop over it. Simply add the current loop index to it and it will work as expected.

```
{%- macro create_delete_modal(id, body, deleteLink) -%}
    {% filter spaceless %}
        <div id="{{ id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

And in your loop pass the loop index:

```
{% for uneInfo in tabInfos[i] %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal-{{ uneInfo.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</button>
            {{ macro.create_delete_modal('deleteModal-'~uneInfo.id, 'Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce package ? ', path('paquets_delete', {'id':uneInfo.id, 'type': unType['typeUtilisateur']})) }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! Super the macro system! So I used what you gave me. However, when I click on my delete button, it does not take into account the current element, but the very first element of the list. I will edit my post to better explain with images and code. But in my opinion, it's a mistake on my part, but I do not see where

Comment: It's already much better! It actually removes the ones I ask, but up to a certain limit.
When there is only one package in each type of user (a package for CIRCO and a package for 1st degree (see my screenshot in my post)), well if I decide to remove the package for 1st degree, it will delete the one for CIRCO. Would this come from the loop when there is only one element left in each type? Or maybe an error in my code that I only discover now?

Comment: it seems to come from the macro. I tested using my removal methods without using the modal, and it works well. The wrong thing would not come in the loop?

Comment: Look at my edit, the problem was the parent loop but this should be solved now

Comment: Indeed, using anInfo.id seems a good solution! However, after changing this, nothing happens when I click on the delete button on my index (the first one to display the modal), it's very strange

Comment: Ok it was me, a typo. However, the problem came back, this time, when I want to delete a 1st degree package, it removes me immediately the 1st in the CIRCO list

EDIT: It's okay now, decidedly, I made a mistake again! Everything seems to work, thank you very much for your help!